# Creating a graph data structure in python using classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, graph-algorithm

I am trying to create some type of class that will be generic enough to be used for both trees and graphs.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, children=[]):
        self.value = value
        self.children = children

    def add_child(self, child):
        self.children.append(child)

    def add_children(self, list_of_children):
        for child in list_of_children:
            self.add_child(child)

def letterGraph():
    a = Node('A')
    b = Node('B')
    c = Node('C')
    d = Node('D')
    c = Node('C')
    e = Node('E')
    f = Node('F')
    g = Node('G')

    a.add_children([b, c])
    b.add_children([a, d, e])
    c.add_children([a, d])
    d.add_children([b, c, e, g, f])
    e.add_children([b, d, g])
    f.add_children([d, g])
    g.add_children([e, d, f])

    return a
```

It seems to work fine with trees, but with respect to graphs, when it adds a child to the current node, it will also add that same child to current node's children nodes.

> example:
>
> current_node: a
>
> a.add_children([b,c])
>
> current_node.children: [b,c]
>
> b.children: [b,c]`

Comment: `def __init__(self, value, children=[]):` is extremely dangerous in Python, as the default parameter is evaluated at the time the function is _defined_, not at the time the function is called (and it's such an easy error to make). So the default is always _the same array_. Use `...children=None`, and if children are none then children = []. [Official docs link](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments)

Comment: +1 to the above comment. In general, for default parameters, best practice is to use only immutable objects; otherwise use `None` and replace them inside the function/method blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed with the help of @amadan

```
infinity = float('inf')

class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, children = None, depth=None):
        self.value = value
        self.children = children
        self.depth = depth

    def add_child(self, child, depth= None):
        if self.children is None:
            self.children = [child]
            self.depth = depth
        else:
            self.children.append(child)

    def add_child_by_value(self, value):
        self.children.add_child(Node(value))

    def add_children(self, list_of_children):
        for child in list_of_children:
            self.add_child(child)

    def is_leaf(self):
        return self.children is None
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally wouldn't call this in the constructor at all. You're not using so why would you have it there?

Also helpful to use `__repr__` to make it more readable when testing.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):    # Take children out of constructor
        self.value = value
        self.children = []     # Initialise children in the function

    def add_child(self, child):
        self.children.append(child)

    def add_children(self, list_of_children):
        for child in list_of_children:
            self.add_child(child)

    def __repr__(self): 
        return self.value    # I am not a machine 

def letterGraph():
    a = Node('A')
    b = Node('B')
    c = Node('C')
    d = Node('D')
    c = Node('C')
    e = Node('E')
    f = Node('F')
    g = Node('G')

    a.add_children([b, c])
    b.add_children([a, d, e])
    c.add_children([a, d])
    d.add_children([b, c, e, g, f])
    e.add_children([b, d, g])
    f.add_children([d, g])
    g.add_children([e, d, f])

    print(a.children)
    print(b.children)


letterGraph()
```

Comment: I used the children variable  in other ways than I have gave an example here. This would not work for me.